# Linux File system auto extend

Tags: filesystems

Is it possible to extend the mounted file system in auto ?

ex: my file system /sap/MAX/saparch1 is getting full frequently.

How to make it ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h /sap/MAX/saparch1 |
awk '{print $(NF -1),$NF}' |
sed "s/%//g" |
awk '$1 > "80" {print "sh autoextend.sh"}'
```

I have taken threshold as 80%.

If the partition is LVM, add a new device as LVM then pvcreate the same. Then add the same to vg of `/sap/MAX/saparch1`.

```
vgextend vgname pvname
lvresize -L +sizeyouwanttoadd  -n lvname vgname
resize2fs lvpath
```

Schedule the script in crontab for checking every particular time.

Comment: Hi Praveen ....really useful... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can You please vote for the same

Comment: @Praveen, would you mind taking the time to format your answers properly? They are rather hard to read. Watch out for smart quotes in your command snippets too, they make it impossible for readers to copy and paste your code.

Comment: @StephenKitt Can you suggest please how can we post answers in proper format

Comment: @Praveen, read the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), don’t use code formatting for non-code (see how your other answers have been edited), write proper sentences, and use the correct quotes in code (straight single and double quotes, not curly quotes). For the latter, the ideal way of writing code here is to copy and paste working code from a terminal ;-).